# IE exec command rich text editing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, richtextediting

I'm tring to insert an image in a WYSIWYG editor, but I can't insert images in Internet Explorer(6/7), although it works fine within Firefox. It fails without throwing any errors.

This is what I'm using:

```
execCommand('insertImage', false, 'absolute/path/to/an/image');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, but as it turned out my problem appeared because IE couldn't insert the image if my iframe (the richeditor container) didn't have focus. So I used the following code just before trying to use execCommand and it worked.

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.focus();
```

Comment: It works!!!! IE was driving me crazy! That's alot! Just shows you that information over 2 years ago is still helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In IE, execCommand exists on the document object, not the window object. (Well, it also exists on range objects, too, but anyway.)

Try:

```
document.execCommand("insertImage", false, "absolute/path/to/an/image");
```